# External CSS not possible with CMS, need to restructure table with inline CSS

Tags: css, html, html-table, content-management-system

I'm currently trying to restyle some tables, and only after I finished the separate CSS and HTML files I realized that our CMS tool goes crazy when I try to refer to another external stylesheet. I've looked around and it seems like some people suggest iframes to deal with this issue, but I'd prefer not to if possible.

What I think needs to happen is go with inline style tags, but I'm not sure how to recreate some of this stuff with inline code. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I've updated the code below with the in-line version. I know it's messy but there aren't really any other options so far. The one really big issue that I'm now running into is compatibility with IE7 *sigh*. I wish I could drop support for that browser, but I'm still getting about 6% of traffic from IE7...

Any ideas on how to ensure compatibility with IE7 at this point?

```
<table border="1px" bordercolor="#898A8A" style="height:auto    ; width:520px; border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>

        <th colspan="2" style="font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:25px; background:#000000; padding:3px;zoom:1;"><span style=" color:#FFF; float:left; text-align:center; padding-left:54px;zoom:1;">Title 1</span><span style=" zoom:1;color:#FFF; padding-left:65px;">Title 2</span><span><div style=" zoom:1;display:inline-block; border-bottom:15px solid transparent; border-right: 15px solid white; position:relative; left:4px; top:-4px; float:top; float:right;"></div></span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style=" background:#d1d3d4;">
        <td style="width:190px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 9px 10px 10px;">Content1</td>
        <td style="width:310px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 9px 10px 10px;">Content2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#ffffff;">
        <td style="width:190px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 9px 10px 10px;">Content3</td>
        <td style="width:310px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 9px 10px 10px;">Content4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style=" background:#d1d3d4;">
        <td style="width:190px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 9px 10px 10px;">Content5</td>
        <td style="width:310px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 9px 10px 10px;">Content6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background:#ffffff;">
        <td style="width:190px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 9px 10px 10px;">Content7</td>
        <td style="width:310px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 9px 10px 10px;">Content8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style=" background:#d1d3d4;">
        <td style="width:190px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 9px 10px 10px;"><div style="display:inline-table;margin-bottom:-23px;">Content9</div><span><div style="border-top:15px solid transparent;  
        border-left:15px solid #898A8A; position:relative;float:left;right:11px;top:14px;"></div></span><span><div style="border-top:15px solid transparent;  
        border-left:15px solid white; position:relative;float:left; right:26px;top:15px;"></div></span>                 
        </td>

        <td style="width:310px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px 9px 10px 10px;;"Content10</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Inline styles are the plague of HTML, avoid them if possible. Also, you could explain this "`tool goes crazy`". Quite possibly it can be solved, so you won't have to create some hideous mess with inline styles.

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: yes, what cms do you use, and could you possibly try putting your new css in the head tag as above? What files do you have editable access to?

Comment: It's a CMS that was custom built by a small web shop our company works with. It's not mainstream by any shot - I think they're running like 30 clients on it. It does work really well though. I'm going to post the inline styles and my latest progress...